# Copy modified files from one server to other

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, find, cp, remote

Scenario:

2 Servers (*.12 and *.13)

CakePHP "application" on both of them.

```
*.12 is "Production" Server
*.13 is "Development" Server
```

Now I want to copy all files modified in the last 2 days from the test server to the production server WITHOUT the directory ./tmp

I can find them on the production server with:

```
find ./ -type d -name tmp -prune -o  -mtime -2 -exec ls {} \;
```

On both servers I have only ssh access.

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't grab things only modified in the last two days, you probably want `rsync` to keep your files in sync:

```
rsync -av --delete --exclude=./tmp/* ./ user@production:/path/
```

For the find command, you can uses `scp`:

```
find ./ -type d -name tmp -prune -o  -mtime -2 -exec bash -c 'scp "$1" user@production:/path/"$1"' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks.. will need to setup rsync then on the development first i think...

Comment: @MichaelGrenzer It's installed by default on most Linux systems. The transfer is done over SSH.